# Apache FTPClient: IOException - Connection timed out

Tags: java, apache, ioexception, ftp-client, connection-timeout

While trying to retrieveFile() using Apache's FTPClient, I sometimes get IOException with the message "Connection timed out".

Does it mean that my FTP Control Connection has timed out or my FTP data connection has timed out ?

What should my application do in such a case, should it create a new FTP Connection or can it re-use the same FTP connection to try and retrieve the file again from the remote FTP server?

Comment: Whoa there, don't immediately jump to writing to code to work around this issue. First things first: investigate WHY you get sporadic connection time outs. Perhaps the server isn't feeling well and needs some care. You can't program away network instabilities, you'll only end up with automated chaos. I'd really do the hard thing and investigate further, which probably means needing the help of administrators. Good luck :(

Comment: FTP Server from where I am pulling files is beyond my control and y program should be able to handle all sorts of failures.
My question is that if I get IOException while trying to retrieve the file with the message "Connection Timed Out", do I need to establish a new control connection or is it fine to try and re-use the same control connection to try and re-fetch the file again...